# Is an SGS Automotive inspection as reliable as an inspection by a local mechanic?

Tags: inspection

eBay motors recommends that vehicles be inspected by SGS Automotive, a professional vehicle inspection service. The alternative would be to hire a local mechanic to do the inspection.

My main concern in buying a car I cannot see is that the car has been in an accident or has been flooded.

Is SGS going to rubber stamp a car, or will they do an inspection as well as a custom-hired mechanic?

Comment: It's best you contact them directly, and check legal clauses to sue them in case of negligence and failure to carry out a through inspection.

Comment: most of the clauses will come down to : caveat emptor ...